# Media query is ignoring "medium" selection

Tags: css, html

I am using media query to size a single block of code out for several view port sizes. The issue I am having is that above and below my "medium" location, everything works as expected, between the 992 and 1199 sizes, it ignores my styles.

CSS

```
 /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@@media screen (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .smallDevices {
      padding-bottom:30px;
      margin-bottom:10px;
      height: 750px;
    }
    .smallScreenStyle{
     height: 750px;
     margin-bottom:10px;

    }
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@@media screen (min-width: 992px) and (max-width:1199px) {
    .midScreenStyle{
        height:650px
    }
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .largeScreenStyle{
       height:650px;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12 no-padding backgroundImageForPage smallScreenStyle midScreenStyle largeScreenStyle" > **strong text**</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I haven't seen this before - why do you have `@@media` as opposed to `@media`?

Comment: @Serlite I am using razor view syntax, this is inside of an asp.net project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for combining media features and media types:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width:1199px)
```

Notice the ***and*** between the media type and the media feature

Comment: Oh for crying out loud. Then your mobile breakpoint wasn't working, either. That would've been good to know.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't how media queries are intended to be used. You don't define different classes for the various breakpoints. Use one.

```
@@media screen (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    ...
    .screenStyle{
         height: 750px;
         margin-bottom:10px;
    }
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@@media screen (min-width: 992px) and (max-width:1199px) {
    .screenStyle{
        height:650px
    }
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .screenStyle{
       height:650px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I reworked my css, but I am still not getting the break between 1199 and 991